# Use of unresolved identifier: kCGWindowImageDefault (and other Core Graphics constants)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I'm new to Swift development. I'm writing an app for MacOS (not iOS) in Swift, and am trying to adapt some of the code from [this Apple sample Objective-C project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) for use in my program.

The problem I'm hitting is that certain Apple-defined constants such as [`kCGWindowImageDefault`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgwindowimageoption/kcgwindowimagedefault) and [`kCGWindowListOptionAll`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/window_list_option_constants?language=objc) are causing XCode to report the compile-time error "Use of unresolved identifier [identifier]".

Somewhat surprisingly, though, if I right-click `kCGWidowImageDefault` and select "Jump to Definition", XCode *does* jump to the definition of that constant (in CoreGraphics > CGWindow.h > CGWindowImageOption) -- so XCode does seem to know what that constant is.

Here are the relevant snippets of my ViewController.swift file:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreGraphics

class ViewController: NSViewController {

...

    func myFunction() {

        // *** XCode reports the error on kCGWindowImageDefault on this line:
        let imageOptions : CGWindowImageOption = kCGWindowImageDefault 

        ...
    }
}
```

The Apple documentation (as linked above) doesn't indicate what needs to be `import`ed for these constants to be used.

XCode *does* appear to successfully recognize the types I'm using such as `CGWindowImageOption` -- it's just the constants that it isn't recognizing.

What do I need to do in order to successfully be able to use `kCGWindowImageDefault` and similar constants in my Swift MacOS program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kCGWindowImageDefault` is only for Objective-C, not Swift. In Swift, `CGWindowImageOption` is an `OptionSet`. For the default you simply use an empty option set:

```
let imageOptions : CGWindowImageOption = []
```

For `CGWindowListOption` you can do:

```
let listOptions: CGWindowListOption = .optionAll
```

Be sure you look at the Swift reference documentation for these enumerations. You can't use the Objective-C values.